# Show div on change select inside Modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Hi I have a popup modal with a  parameter. I want to show something onchange of the  down the parameter. I have just use code as bellow:

```
    <script>
$(function(){
  $("#payment_type").change(function(){
    alert($('#payment_type').val());
    $("#fiscreport").load("vat_fisc.php?fiscyr="+$('#payment_type').val());

    });  
 });
</script>
```

and

```
<select name="payment_currecny">
      <option value="EUR">EURO</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
      <option value="TK">TK</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
```

I set alart but i couldn't be able to get any response.
Any help?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Any errors in the console?

Comment: here is the error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function another error i just got: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isOpen' when i use like this <script>
$(function(){
    $("[name=payment_currency]").change(function(){
        alert($('[name=payment_currency]').val());
        $("#fiscreport").load("vat_fisc.php?fiscyr="+$('[name=payment_currency]').val());

    });  
 });
</script>

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code. The code you've shown is not the one causing that error.

Comment: in details the error show:cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isOpen' jquery-1.9.1.js?_=1402871563693:507
jQuery.extend.error jquery-1.9.1.js?_=1402871563693:507
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js?_=1402871563694:487
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.9.1.js?_=1402871563693:648
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.9.1.js?_=1402871563693:270
$.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js?_=1402871563694:483
(anonymous function) po_list.php:83
x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
v.handle

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to call the dialog open method before initializing the dialog. I'm sorry we cannot provide further help without the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the correct selector.  You should use "[name=payment_currency]".

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("[name=payment_currency]").change(function(){
        alert($('[name=payment_currency]').val());
        $("#fiscreport").load("vat_fisc.php?fiscyr="+$('[name=payment_currency]').val());

    });  
 });
</script>
```